# Make an object appendable by jQuery

Tags: jquery, object, append

jQuery has the function `append` that can be used like this:

```js
$(whatever).append('abc') // Append string
$(whatever).append(document.createElement('div')) // Append an element
$(whatever).append($('<div></div>')) // Passing a jQuery object
```

The last one means that the jQuery object must have some function (as JS has no types and it's just an object) which returns the append function the html in some way, or something similar.

In order to make my code as nice as possible, I wanted to make something like:

```js
class Component {
    name;

    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    FUNCTIONREFERED() {
        return $(document.createElement('input'))
            .attr('name', this.name);
    }
}

$('body').append(new Component('example'));
```

I have looked at the documentation and found nothing, I also took a look at the properties and functions of the object that is returned and saw nothing special.

I tried a few, imagine it was the `html` function (to say an example), then I could return the closure so jQuery could paint it:

```js
class Component {
    name;

    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    html() {
        return $(document.createElement('input'))
            .attr('name', this.name)
            .html;
    }
}

$('body').append(new Component('example'));
```

I **don't** want to pass a string like this:

```js
$('body').append(new Component('example').html());
```

I want the object itself to be appendable like the jQuery object is.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you need. Can you provide a clear example of what the result should be? If you want the "Object" to return a jQuery, so it can be used like this: `$('body').append(new Component('example').append('<p>Hello</p>'))`, you can do simply `class Component {
    constructor(name) {
        return $('<input />').attr('name', name)
    }
}`
Or, better use only a simple arrow function: `const myComponent = name => $('<input />').attr('name', name)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some comments suggested, it is possible to return another object in the constructor of a class in JS.

So it could be something like:

```js
class Component {
    constructor() {
        return $('<div>Hello World!</div>');
    }
}

$('body').append(new Component());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It does not behave like a jQuery object, it becomes one. It's acceptable!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Component{
  name;
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  html(){
    return $(document.createElement('input')).attr('name', this.name);
  }
}

$('body').append(new Component('example').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This does not make the object appendable, for how it is designed I need that the object Component behaves like a jQuery object in that sense.

Comment: You can write the same return statement in constructor function itself. return with an object returns that object, in all other cases the class instance is returned.

Comment: That'd be a good solution, I didn't know you could return another object in the constructor in JS. Good to know, thanks!